# Understanding sendfile() and splice()

Tags: linux, splice, sendfile

`sendfile()` can be used to transmit data from a "file" descriptor to a "socket" descriptor in order to get data from machine A to machine B. Is it possible to get the data at the receiving end from the "socket" descriptor to a file with similar zero-copy semantics? I think `sendfile()` doesn't help here because `sendfile()` needs the source of data to be "page/buffer" cache. Is my understanding correct? Can `splice()` help in this situation?

Answer (score 17):

You're correct about the limitation of `sendfile` for this. And yes, `splice` can help, but it's not trivial: `splice` requires that at least one of the source or target file descriptors be a pipe. So you can't directly `splice` from a socket to a plain file descriptor.

Conceptually, what you can do to make it work is:

- setup your inbound socket fd and your output file fd as you would normally
- create a pipe with [`pipe(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html)
- in a loop:

- read from the socket to the write side of the pipe with [`splice`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/splice.2.html)
- write from the read side of the pipe to the file with `splice` also

Repeat the last steps until all the data is read.

[Zero-Copy in Linux with sendfile() and splice()](https://blog.superpat.com/zero-copy-in-linux-with-sendfile-and-splice) has an implementation of this technique.

Comment: Since 2.6.33 the out_fd for sendfile can be any file descriptor (not just sockets).

Comment: since 4.2 the same goes for `splice()`

Comment: @techno Man pages I can locate for `splice()` still say fd_in or fd_out needs to be a pipe. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Greg  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2b514574f7e88c8498027ee366fd6e7aae5aa4b5

Comment: @technosaurus that commit deals with splice from unix domain socket _to pipe_ hence doesn't contradict the statement, and splice does in fact (today, in kernel 5.1.3) still require either fd_in or fd_out (or both) to be a pipe